# Angular - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index

Tags: angular

In my Angular-13, I have this code:

button.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-button',
    templateUrl: './button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonComponent {
    @Input() type: string = 'button';
    @Input() block: boolean = false;
    @Input() color: string = 'primary';
    @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
    @Input() loading: boolean = false;
    @Input() icon!: string | null;

    public icons = {
        facebook: 'fab fa-facebook',
        google: 'fab fa-google',
        googlePlus: 'fab fa-google-plus'
    };

    constructor() {}
}
```

button.component.html:

```
<button
    [type]="type"
    class="btn btn-{{ color }}"
    [ngClass]="{'btn-block': block}"
    [disabled]="disabled || loading"
>
    <i *ngIf="!!icon" class="mr-2" [ngClass]="icons[icon]"></i>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <span
        *ngIf="loading"
        class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm ml-2"
        role="status"
        aria-hidden="true"
    ></span>
</button>
```

But I got this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ facebook: string; google: string; googlePlus: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ facebook: string; g
```

I got this highlighted:

> icons[icon]

I changed **@Input() icon!: string | null**   to   **@Input() icon: string = null** yet it is not resolved.

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['string' can't be used to index type '{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350092/string-cant-be-used-to-index-type)

Comment: Try public icons: Record<string, string> = {..}