# What does "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'." mean?

Tags: typescript

```
const foo = {};

['bar', 'baz'].forEach((word) => {
    foo[word] = []
});
```

The above gives me the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

How do I fix this? You can try it here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeBfA3AKBwbQHIAjAQwCdCAaGE0gL0IF0A6BcgUVOAAsAKPgHcQ5ACYBKFAD50OGPPiJ8wsUxQx8THBnFYgA.

Comment: This has been answered several times on StackOverflow, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350092/string-cant-be-used-to-index-type), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568423/typescript-no-index-signature-with-a-parameter-of-type-string-was-found-on-ty), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b).

Comment: I read some of those and still didn't understand, hence why I asked. The answer below is perfect.

Comment: Thank you for posting the question. The answer was easy to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your object seems to have dynamic keys, you should specify it in the type of `foo`.

The solution for your particular case would be

```
const foo : {
    [key: string]: string[] // whatever type of array
} = {};

['bar', 'baz'].forEach((word) => {
    foo[word] = []
});
```

This tells that `foo` is a type of object which takes in keys of type `string` and the corresponding type of value for it will be `string[]`